# PHP - If variable is not empty, echo some html code

Tags: php, html, variables

I would like to display some html code if a variable is not empty, else I would like to display nothing.

I've tried this code but doesn't work:

```
<?php 
    $web = the_field('website');
    if (isset($web)) {
?>
       <span class="field-label">Website: </span><a href="http://<?php the_field('website'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('website'); ?></a> 
<?php
    } else { 
        echo "Niente";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Jack Maney - I believe that's an auto WordPress function that outputs the given field name.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
if (!empty($web)) {
?>
    <span class="field-label">Website:  </span><a href="http://<?php the_field('website'); ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_field('website'); ?></a> 
<?php
} else { echo "Niente";}
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: There should be an `!` before your empty call, as that is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 22):

`isset` will return **true** even if the variable is "". `isset` returns false only if a variable is **null**. What you should be doing:

```
if (!empty($web)) {
    // foo
}
```

This will check that he variable is not empty.

Hope this helps

Comment: The OP should be using a plain, simple `if ($web)`. No need for `empty` here, it just has the potential to hide mistakes unnecessarily.

Comment: I don't see how `if(!empty($var))` can create confusion, but I do agree that `if ($var)` is simpler.

Comment: Because `empty` has the specific purpose of suppressing errors for nonexistent variables. You don't want to suppress errors unless you need to. [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) explains the problem in detail.

Answer (score 14):

Simply use `if ($web)`. This is `true` if the variable has any *truthy* value.

You don't need `isset` or `empty` since you know the variable exists, since you have just set it in the previous line.

Comment: This is the best answer. It seems few people know this.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't see how `if(!empty($var))` can create confusion, but I do agree that `if ($var)` is simpler. – *vanneto [Mar 8 '12 at 13:33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592855/php-if-variable-is-not-empty-echo-some-html-code#comment12204591_9592890)*
>
> > Because `empty` has the specific purpose of suppressing errors for nonexistent variables. You don't want to suppress errors unless you need to. The [Definitive Guide To PHP's `isset` And `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset/) explains the problem in detail. – *deceze♦ [Mar 9 '12 at 1:24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592855/php-if-variable-is-not-empty-echo-some-html-code#comment12219168_9592890)*

Focusing on the error suppression part, if the **variable is an array** where a **key** being accessed **may or may not be defined**:

1. `if($web['status'])` would produce:

   > ***Notice**: Undefined index: status*
2. To access that key without triggering errors:

   1. `if(isset($web['status']) && $web['status'])` (2nd condition is not tested if the 1st one is `FALSE`) OR
   2. `if(!empty($web['status']))`.

However, as [*deceze♦* pointed out](http://an%20error%20free%20method%20to%20access%20that%20key), a *truthy* value of a defined variable makes `!empty` redundant, but you still need to remember that PHP assumes the following examples as `FALSE`:

- `null`
- `''` or `""`
- `0.0`
- `0`
- `'0'` or `"0"`
- `'0' + 0 + !3`

So if *zero* is a meaningful status that you want to detect, you should actually use string and numeric comparisons:

3. Error free and *zero* detection:

   ```
   if(isset($web['status'])){
     if($web['status'] === '0' || $web['status'] === 0 ||
        $web['status'] === 0.0 || $web['status']) {
       // not empty: use the value
     } else {
       // consider it as empty, since status may be FALSE, null or an empty string
     }
   }
   ```

   The generic condition (`$web['status']`) should be left at the end of the entire statement.

Comment: An [3v4l example with a converted object into an array depicting `property_exists`, `isset`, `array_key_exists` and `empty`](https://3v4l.org/1hLkj) shows that `isset` always detects if the variable has been assigned a non-null value and `array_key_exists` always detects if the key is accessible.

Comment: `isset && !empty` is redundant. Just `!empty` will do exactly the same.

Comment: @deceze It has been a while but you're right: `empty` does seem to absorb/suppress all notices/errors, avoiding the "Undefined offset/index" notice to be thrown due to a non-existing key in the array (even in PHP v4.4.9, just tested :). I adjusted the answer, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `isset`, what `isset` does is check if the variable is set ('exists') and is not `NULL`. What you're looking for is `empty`, which checks if a variable is empty or not, even if it's set. To check what is empty and what is not take a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php for what `isset` does exactly, so you understand why it doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: This is the best way if you have to check a variable that contains numbers. As in the refernce shown, `$e = 0; echo empty($e)` will return false too. It does not matter in what format we provide the number. (String, Float, int) See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($web))
{
   echo 'Something';
}
```

Comment: This worked good:
   <?php 
   $web = get_field('website');
   if (!empty($web)) 
{ 
    echo "<span class='field-label'>Website:  </span><a href='http://<?php the_field('website'); ?> target='_blank'><?php the_field('website'); ?></a>";

} 

else { echo "Niente";}

?>

But i can't see the true link, I see this output:
WEBSITE: target='_blank'>

Answer (score 0):

```
if($var !== '' && $var !== NULL)
{
   echo $var;
}
```

Comment: This is less elegant than deceze's answer -- which is the most professional technique on the page.

Comment: deceze's technique does not work when variable have false value and question is about check if variable is not empty.

Comment: Then I guess it comes down to what you consider `empty`. Deceze is very careful to explain that his check is "truthy".  If the OP specifically expects a boolean `false` value, that is not clear in the question.  Your unexplained answer does not speak of allowing boolean `false` values.

Comment: I don't Wordpress.  Does `the_field()` return `false` AND would the OP want to handle it as a non-empty outcome if it does? I reckon not.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your use of `the_field()`, which is for Advanced Custom Fields, a wordpress plugin.

If you want to use a field in a variable you have to use this: `$web = get_field('website');`.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work too, try using"is_null"

```
<?php 
$web = the_field('website');
if (!is_null($web)) {
?>

....html code here

<?php
} else { 
    echo "Niente";
}
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

hope that suits you..