# How to avoid a break line if the variable is empty?

Tags: php

I passed this variable in email, but if some of this is empty, the white space remains.

```
$mail->Body = 'Risposta:<br/>'
    . $panoramica . '<br/>'
    . $mare . '<br/>'
    . $paese . '<br/>'
    . $ristorante . '<br/>'
    . $piscina . '<br/><br/>';
```

for example if `$ristorante` and `$piscina` are empty, 2 white spaces remain below.

Comment: `. (empty($panoramica) ? '' : $panoramica . '<br/>')` and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - If variable is not empty, echo some html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592855/php-if-variable-is-not-empty-echo-some-html-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your string in many ways. For example, make a decision per variable:

```
$body  = 'Risposta:<br/>';

$body .= !empty($panoramica) ? $panoramica . '<br/>' : '';
$body .= !empty($mare) ? $mare . '<br/>' : '';
$body .= !empty($paese) ? $paese . '<br/>' : '';
$body .= !empty($ristorante) ? $ristorante . '<br/>' : '';
$body .= !empty($piscina) ? $piscina . '<br/>' : '';

$mail->Body = $body . '<br/>';
```

Comment: Two things. In my opinion it is better to use non negative conditions and double quotes instead of string concat: `$body .= empty($panoramica) ? '' : "$panoramica<br/>";`

Comment: @DamianDziaduch why? It's perfectly clear as it is. Do you have any insight about it or is it just gut feeling?

Comment: Regarding double quotes, It is just my peronal opinion, like spaces vs tabs ;) But non negatives conditions from what I remember I read about that in a Uncle Bob book, but I am not sure 100% :)

Comment: @DamianDziaduch I respect you personal choices. But please don't telling anyone that something is _better_, if it is primarily opinion based. ;) But thank you for your suggestion, maybe someone else want to do it this way.

Comment: @eisbehr I wrote that it is just my opion :)

Comment: @DamianDziaduch You wrote in your _opinion it is better to_ do it as you wrote. Then it's not only an opinion and you need to deliver reasons _why_ it is _better_.

Comment: @eisbehr you are right, that might be confusing, I will amend. EDIT: I cant't :X

Comment: No problems here, just for the next time. ;) @DamianDziaduch

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$body = "Risposta:<br/>";

if ($panoramica != '') {
    $body.= $panoramica . "<br/>";
}

if ($mare != '') {
    $body.= $mare . "<br/>";
}

if ($paese != '') {    
    $body.= $paese . "<br/>";
}

if ($ristorante != '') {
    $body.= $ristorante . "<br/>";
}

if ($piscina != '') {
    $body.= $piscina . "<br/><br/>";
}

$mail->Body = $body;
```

Comment: This code-snippet could sure use some proper formatting and intending.

Comment: I think ternary statements would be much better here --

Comment: Beside this, the additional line-break at the end will only appended if the last variable has content.

Answer (score 0):

Build your string separately and test each part:

```
$body = 'Riposta<br/>';

if(strlen($panoramica)) $body .= $panoramica . '<br/>';
if(strlen($mare)) $body .= $mare . '<br/>';
// etc

$mail->Body = $body;
```